# Ruby script not seeing external changes to a file it created depending on where it's run

Tags: ruby, file-io

A colleague recently wrote a Ruby script which prompts for user input by opening a temporary file in an external text editor with some initialized text, and then acts upon it once the editor is closed.  This behavior is similar to how git handles commit/tag editing.

```rb
require 'tempfile'

@command = options[:cmd] || "vim"
@file = Tempfile.new("buffer")
@file.write("This is the initial text in the file")
puts @file.read
@pid = Kernel.spawn("#{@command} #{@file.path}")
Process.wait(@pid)
@file.rewind
contents = @file.read
# Do stuff with "contents"
```

The script worked fine for a number of my colleagues, but when I ran it, it wouldn't pick up the changes I made to the temp file: it still treated the temporary file as though it had the initialized text.  I tracked the issue down to how it's reading the file; `@file.rewind` is not sufficient to have it pick up the changes.  I can get it to work if instead of re-reading the file through the file object, I instead create a new file per `File.new(@file.path)`.  I therefore suspect that the file contents are being buffered when I run it, but not when they do.

I am using Ruby 2.4.0p0 on macOS 10.12.2.  This is working for a colleague using Ruby 2.0.0p643 on OS X 10.11.6, and for another colleague using 2.3.0-p0 on Ubuntu.  I confirmed that it does not work for me on my machine when I use Ruby 2.0.0p648, so I'm suspecting that this may be due to the OS difference and not the Ruby difference.

Note that I have done very little work in Ruby, so I might be missing something obvious.

My questions are therefore:

1. What is causing the discrepancy, and is it documented somewhere?  Was there a change in Ruby that causes this to be buffered?  Is it an OS thing?  Is it specifically left unspecified somewhere whether this will or will not be buffered?  I'm not seeing anything obvious in the [IO Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html), though I could be looking in the wrong place.
2. What is a preferred Ruby idiom for this that will work across OS versions?  Or is the close-and-reopen approach my best shot?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on a similar env as you (mac/ruby 2.4.x).  Here's is the full script where contents changes in the temp buffer.

```
require 'tempfile'

options = {}
@command = options[:cmd] || "nano"
@file = Tempfile.new("buffer")
@file.write("This is the initial text in the file")
puts @file.read
@pid = Kernel.spawn("#{@command} #{@file.path}")
Process.wait(@pid)
@file.rewind
contents = @file.read

puts contents
```

I changed it to `nano` but `vim` worked too.  Maybe your vim config is interferring?

My test:

1. If the temp buffer is edited to say "Hey" (save/exit) then `puts contents` says Hey.  I think this is what you wanted.